# How to solve the problem with a broken font "Merriweather" on iOS?

Tags: css, fonts

I tried to get the font "Merriweather" to work in different ways:

1. Connection via

   ```
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

   doesn't work;
2. Took the font [here](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/merriweather?subsets=cyrillic,latin) with the required parameters

   ```
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'Merriweather';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/merriweather-v22-latin_cyrillic-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Merriweather Regular'), local('Merriweather-Regular'),
         url('../fonts/merriweather-v22-latin_cyrillic-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/merriweather-v22-latin_cyrillic-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/merriweather-v22-latin_cyrillic-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/merriweather-v22-latin_cyrillic-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('../fonts/merriweather-v22-latin_cyrillic-regular.svg#Merriweather') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
   }
   ```

   doesn't work.
3. Generated .woff, .woff2, .svg and .ttf in [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) - doesn't work.

I specify the font for the tag as follows:

```
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
```

What could be the problem? This is the only font that does not work on iOS (Chrome, Safari) and works on Android, the other two are in order, connected in the above ways.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, very simple, but not immediately obvious to me. Third option with Font Squirrel works if you select Custom Subsetting and check Language when creating in Expert mode. [image: click]